# Unittest function?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, unit-testing

There is a code where I test the site, namely the name validation string, all the names are written in excel.
I parsed excel via pandas, but I don't understand how to handle line by line. Updated: I wrote for, and put a function in it to which values are passed, but the tests fall after the first one with an indication of the last line error True

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

URL = 'https://psy.edu.ru/'

class check_psyedu(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Алексей\YandexDisk\Job\Python\Test\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
    
    i = 0
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\Users\\Алексей\\YandexDisk\\Job\\Python\\Test\\list_name.xlsx')
    for row in df.itertuples():
        def test_box_name(self):
            #df.loc[0]
            driver = self.driver
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.get(URL)
            name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
            button= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/div[1]/button')
            name.send_keys(df.loc[{i}])
            button.click()
    i += 1

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. What is supposed to happen when you run the code? What happens instead, and how is that different? "but I don't understand how to handle line by line" What do you mean by "handle"? What do you need to do with each line (I assume you mean, each row of the spreadsheet)? Also: what exactly are you trying to use `unittest` for? I don't see any actual use of the testing functionality (like `assertEquals` etc.), only the setup and teardown for tests. How will you know if the web site responded properly to the button click?

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Normally, we use test frameworks and unit testing to test local code, in the same language - not the interaction with a web site. It's hard to understand the question because it's hard to be sure what parts of the code are actually *related to the problem*.